# While loop increment and decrement

Tags: c

I'm trying to increment and decrement values based on a single user input within the range 1-9.
eg. if user enters 5, program outputs 1234'5'4321. So goal is to have it increment from 1 to inputted number and then decrease from inputted number to 1.
I'm currently able to increment and decrement but it decrements to 0 instead of 1, and then it produces an error that I don't intend for it to produce. The goal was to create this using a while loop and I suspect that my error is generating from my second nested while loop but I'm not sure how to solve it. I tried changing the condition to be "num > 0", with logic that the decrement should end at 1, but that doesn't solve the issue

```
while(num != 0 && num <= 9){
        while(i != num){
            i++;
            printf("%d", i);
        }
            while(num != 0){
                num--;
                printf("%d", num);
        }

    }
    printf("Error: Number exceeds range!\n");
```

Comment: Order matters! In what order do you decrement `num` and print out its value? Some [simple debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) should help you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outer `while` loop allows negative values, which you probably want to avoid, but it does not appear to be necessary for this example anyway.

What you want to do, is start with `i` at `1` and count up with the condition `i < num`. You then print `'num'`, and then decrement `i` while `i > 0`. In this case, print the value before incrementing or decrementing it. So:

```
if (num > 0 && num <= 9) {
    int i = 1; // make sure that you actually instantiate i
    while (i < num) {
        printf("%d", i++); // this increments i after using its value
    }
    printf("'%d'", num); // you could also print i, as i == num at this point
    --i; // decrement i below num
    while (i > 0) {
        printf("%d", i--); // this decrements i after using its value
    }
} else {
    printf("Error: Number exceeds range!\n");
}
```

By using `i++` and `i--` here, the value of `i` is returned and then `i` is incremented/decremented. If you want to use the original value of `i` multiple times before incrementing/decrementing it, then change its value as a separate step.

Your error message was printed in all cases, whether erroneous or not. This is because it came after the `while` loop, so it was always executed, whether the `while` loop was skipped or entered. This is why you should be using an `if` statement with an `else` for the error.

Comment: Your code is more efficient but it still produces the error message and it prints the inputted number twice instead of once now.
eg  I input 5, it prints 1234554321 along with the error message. Why is this?

Comment: @David1083 Fixed: `i` had reached the value of `num` at the end of the second loop, so it started at that value in the second loop. Decrementing it before starting the second loop helped. The reason that you are getting the error, is because it comes outside the outer `while` loop: whether the `while` loop is skipped or entered, the error message will be printed. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

It is because you first decrement the `num` and then print it.

When `num = 1` it enters the loop and decrements to `0` thus printing `0`.

```
if (num != 0 && num <= 9){
        while(i < (num-1)){
            i++;
            printf("%d", i);
        }

        while(num != 0){
           printf("%d", num);
           num--;
        }
    }
```

Also for outer condition you don't need `while` what you need is `if`.

Comment: I tried using this but it prints the inputted number twice and it still produces the "Error: Number exceeds range" error.
eg. I entered 5, it prints 1234554321 and error..
The goal is to have it print 123454321. It did eliminate the decrement running until it reaches 0 but the error still occurs for some reason

Comment: @David1083 "*Error: Number exceeds range*" as it stands this message is printed in any case. There is no condition around its printf-statement nor did you told us any.

Answer (score -3):

```
It works with small modification 
while(num != 0 && num <= 9){
        while(i != num){
            i++;
            printf("%d", i);
        }
            while(num){
               --num;
                if(num)
                printf("%d", num);
        }
}
printf("Error: Number exceeds range!\n");
```

Comment: You have not explained why your "small modification" makes it work, nor is the small modification a very good thing. You have addressed the symptom of the incorrect printing, but not fixed the problems inherent in the original code's approach.